How do I make an emergency call without a cell phone?
Let's suppose I am in an emergency situation and only have a tablet, but no cell phone. How can I contact police for an emergency?

Some tablets have the ability to connect to phone networks, and this may work without a SIM card for 911, however it usually doesn't (even a non-activated SIM card gives a phone number). Otherwise you'd need some other kind of connection, and I'd say that if there's WiFi that makes it close to being off topic - but only close because campsites may have WiFi, as might national park facilities and the like, even when unstaffed. However WiFi dialling is a feature of your device (and I think needs a SIM) so you're more likely to get sensible answers where Android or Apple are the main topics

This situation is what your Personal Locator Beacon or InReach device is for. Being in the Great Outdoors often means there is no cell signal anyway, so plan accordingly.

Please specify if you have internet connection.

I would upvote your question if you told us what kind of situation you were worried about.  For example, the answer for a backcountry hiker would be different from the answer for a driver out of gas on a lonely road would be different for a householder in a power failure hearing someone breaking into his/her house.   Actually, all situations would be amenable to setting off your PLB, if you have one, but this is an expensive option.

Find the nearest person with a phone, cell or otherwise, as you used to need before cell phones were common.
Out in the wilderness most people you meet will make an emergency call for you if they have a working phone. You will be more likely to find people on published campsites and of course at manned entrance gates, both to parks and to businesses.
Flagging down a car on a through road should work, if such a road is near.
As people are used to have a phone on hand the ways to find a phone might not be thought of anymore. First of all, most houses with people inside will either have a working phone or know where to find one near.
If you are in a city or suburb situation you may need to call on a few houses till you find one willing to answer the door. Out in the great outdoors it is more likely that the people in the first house can and will help.
In small villages in an area with poor cellphone connectivity the chances for a phonebooth are higher, center of village is the first place I would look there.
There might be options with a tablet if you have an internet connection, but those are beyond what fits this site.
If you are away from where you can expect other people you should have prepared, like a satellite telephone or a personal locator. No use to wish for one of those if you did not prepare.
In the worst places the nearest place to ask for help might be a few days of hard walking away and the nearest human being not any closer in any direction, so being prepared when going out in that kind of area is essential.

This is true, +1, but in plenty of places phone boxes have been removed or disconnected, so options aren't what they used to be. On the other hand in well travelled locations finding someone who does have a phone is more likely these days.

Phoneboxes are not the only phones potentially available.

No, they're not, but they used to be an important option, often well-placed away from human habitation and available 24/7 (unlike a roadside business that might be deserted overnight)

Looking for a phone is indeed your best option, but in plenty of places phone boxes have been removed or disconnected, so that source of an emergency phone has gone.
As usual it comes down to preparedness. Just carry a phone (or choose a tablet that can take a SIM and be used for calls).
In areas where you can expect a mobile phone signal (even if you have to climb a hill to connect) it's worth having one even if you do carry a PLB. For example you might want to tell your safety contact "we're OK but delayed" - and you should have a safety contact especially if you lack emergency communication devices.
A basic handset with a pay-as-you-go SIM costs next to nothing so there's really no reason not to carry one - more than one in a group. It should be kept protected from the elements, or choose a waterproof model, but that still needs to be protected from being dropped or lost.

This falls under being prepared. OP indicates not being prepared and needed to make a call under those circumstances.

@Willeke I was being polite to them while challenging the framing of the question. I don't want to take an overly critical tone but heading out without one is an error that deserves to be addressed
